# Read a csv and write in excel format

Tags: linux, bash, shell, xls

I generate a `csv` file in this format:

```
Group_Name1,member1,member2,member3,...,memberN
Group_Name2,member1,member2,member3,...,memberM
Group_Name3,member1,member2,member3,...,memberR
Group_Name4,member1,member2,member3,...,memberT
....
Group_NameN,memberN,memberN,memberN,...,memberZ
```

I tried to use `awk` but I can't write as desidered.

Now I need to convert this file in this format:

```
Group_Name1,Group_Name2,Group_Name3,Group_Name4,...,Group_NameN
member1,member1,member1,member1,...,memberN
member2,member2,member2,member2,...,memberM
member3,member3,member3,member3,...,memberR
member4,member4,member4,member4,...,memberT
...
memberN,memberN,memberN,memberN,...,memberZ
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   awk -F, '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) a[i,NR]=$i
            max=(max<NF?NF:max)}
            END {for (i=1; i<=max; i++)
                  {for (j=1; j<=NR; j++) 
                      printf "%s%s", a[i,j], (j==NR?RS:FS)
                  }
            }' infile.csv
```

Comment: I'm very sorry. I did click for error, how can remediate it?

Comment: @MarcoFerrara You can just click it again

Comment: I clicked on up! Thanks